I am trying to submit a registered entering details of selling bicycle. When i click submit button the form does not submit and stays on current page
Action in BicycleController:
    public ActionResult SellerAddPage()
    {
        var model = new BikeModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SellerAddPage(BikeModel bicycle, HttpPostedFileBase Image)
    {
            try
            {
                // Save image to folder
                if (Image != null && Image.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName =    Path.GetFileName(Image.FileName);
                    var path =   Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Image"), fileName);
                    Image.SaveAs(path);
                    bicycle.Image = "/Content/Images/" + fileName; // Save the relative path in the database
                }

                int? userId = Session["UserId"] as int?;

                if (userId == null)
                {
                    // Handle case where UserId is not in session (user not logged in or session expired)
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "User is not logged in.";
                    return View(bicycle);
                }
                else
                {
                    bicycle.UserID = userId.Value;
                    // Save bicycle details to the database
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "INSERT INTO [sales].[bicycle] (user_id,brand_name, category_name, description, picture) VALUES (@user_id,@brand_name, @category_name, @description, @picture)";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", bicycle.UserID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand_name", bicycle.Brand);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_name", bicycle.Category);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", bicycle.Description);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", bicycle.Image);

                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    ViewBag.Message = "Bicycle uploaded successfully.";
                    return RedirectToAction("SellerPage");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An error occurred while adding the bicycle: " + ex.Message;
        }

        return View("SellerPage");
    }

Model
public class BikeModel
{
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int BicycleID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListBrand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListCategory {  get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public BikeModel()
    {
        ListBrand = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Value="Electra",Text="Electra"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Haro",Text="Haro"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Heller", Text = "Heller"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Pure Cycles", Text = "Pure Cycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Ritchey", Text = "Ritchey"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Strider", Text = "Strider"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Sun Bicycles", Text = "Sun Bicycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Surly", Text = "Surly"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Trek", Text = "Trek"},
        };

        ListCategory = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Value="Children Bicycles", Text = "Children Bicycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Comfort Bicycles", Text = "Comfort Bicycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Cruisers Bicycles", Text = "Cruisers Bicycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Cyclocross Bicycles", Text = "Cyclocross Bicycles"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Electric Bikes", Text = "Electric Bikes"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Mountain Bikes", Text = "Mountain Bikes"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="Road Bikes", Text = "Road Bikes"},
        };
    }

Here is my view:
@model uXXXXXXX_HW02.Models.BikeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SellerAddPage";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SellerAddPage", "Bicycle", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>BicycleModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Brand, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id="brandId" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class =    "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-  danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-  danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label     col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Image,new {htmlAttributes=new { @class = "form-control" }    })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  formmethod="post" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}

I have tried using many things including get method but I am unable to submit the form and most solutions were pertaining to ASP.NET Core and I work on .NET framework. I also tried recreating the project and add exception handling to in the http post method.
//This code has some probable sql query errors

I suggest you rename your SellerAddPage POST method to something name (for example SellerAddPageAddBicycle), as it is the same method name as the method returning your view which might be causing your issue.
I strongly recommend looking at Developer Tools in your browser tab for console errors and in the network tab to inspect requests made to server, if any.
BTW, don't use GET request to modify data state, POST, alongside PATCH and PUT are suitable for methods changing state.

Hi, thank you for your suggestion .The error was primarily in the sql query being unable to insert data. Rather than retrieving user id from the session, my query tried to retrieve it from the database. Though the form submits, the image somehow is not being displayed. Could you please assist me with that.     here is the view of image being displayed, i declared image as varchar(max) in the database, should i change it to varbinary?
